# How to fix weird padding on top of SingleChildScrollView when appBar is missing?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I have a DraggableScrollableSheet that nests a SingleChildScrollView. When the AppBar from the scaffold is missing, the DSS changes height accordingly, but SCSV appears as if AppBar is still there.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/favlc.jpg),(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX5xg.jpg)

I want to know if there is any other way I can fix this or redo it altogether in another way.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Photo section (half the screen)
          LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/product1.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 20, // Adjust the position as needed
            top: 10, // Adjust the position as needed
            child: SafeArea(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(
                    context,
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Bottom sheet section
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: .40,
            minChildSize: .40,
            maxChildSize: .7,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(17),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(17),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                    //...
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```